# Comparing complexity of Binary Indexed Tree operations with normal approach

Tags: algorithm

I was going through this article to understand BIT : https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/binary-indexed-tree-or-fenwick-tree/#c217533

In this the author says the following at one place:

> If we look at the for loop in update() operation, we can see that the loop runs at most the number of bits in index x which is restricted to be less or equal to n (the size of the given array), so we can say that the update operation takes at most O(log2(n)) time

Then my question is that, if it can go upto n (the size of the given array), then how is the time complexity any different from the normal approach he has mentioned at the starting because in that update should be O(1) ? and prefixsum(int k) can go upto max n.

Comment: in BIT both update & query is `O(log2N)` where N is size of array. Using normal arrays with prefix sums we can get either `O(1)` update and `O(N)` query or vice verse, so if you have both updates & queries BIT is always faster

Comment: Ok but how come the worst case complexity of BIT's update() is not O(N) as the loop can run upto n as well. ?

Comment: `+i&-i` actually gives a lowest power of `2`  such that binary masks of `2^x` and `i` have exacly one bit in common, so the loop will be `+1,+2,+4,+8,...` in worst case which is `O(log2n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is that you don't do a step of 1 in the loop, but a step of the size `x&-x`.
This is equivalent to going upwards in the tree, to the next relevant node that needs to include the current one and thus gives you a worst case of `O(log n)`.